# Intellij IDEA: wrapping certain widget in a container in XML file

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, code-generation

Is there such tool, like in eclipse in refactor menu? It generates container and wraps the selected text in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Surrounding Blocks of Code with Language Constructs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html) help section.